# undefined method `images_will_change!'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am posting a question for first time so please ignore the styling part.
I am using Carrierwave for multiple file uploads.But I am not able to do so.

**API ONLY**

```
Controller code:

def create
@comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
@comment.save
end

def comment_params
params.require(:comment).permit(:description, {images: []})
end
------------
Comment.rb

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 mount_uploaders :images, FileUploader
end
------------
Migration file

class AddImagesToComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
 def change
  add_column :comments, :images, :string, array: true, default: []
 end
end
```

Firstly I am getting **Unpermitted parameter: :images** 
and also
**undefined method `images_will_change!' for Comment**
Can anyone please help me in this.

Comment: Can you please show the view file with your form

Comment: I am creating an api only ,so no form is there.I am using Postman to call my api. @Maxence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to post [Multiple Images Uploading With CarrierWave and PostgreSQL Array](http://bobintornado.github.io/rails/2015/12/29/Multiple-Images-Uploading-With-CarrierWave-and-PostgreSQL-Array.html). You need to update images separately in controller.

```
before_action :set_comment

def create
  add_more_images(images_params[:images])
  flash[:error] = "Failed uploading images" unless @comment.save
  redirect_to :back
end

private
def set_comment
  @comment = Comment.where(id: params[:id]).first || Comment.new
end

def add_more_images(new_images)
  images = @comment.images 
  images += new_images
  @comment.images = images
end

def images_params
  params.require(:comment).permit({images: []}) # allow nested params as array
end
```

Comment: Still getting **Unpermitted parameters:  :images** @Artem Dorodovskyi

Comment: If array is empty you have this error, for fixing it add `params[: comment][:images] ||= []`
or remove braces for params `params.require(:comment).permit(:images)`

Comment: The problem i was facing was that i was getting images in params.It got resloved using @comment.images = params[:comment][:images].